Password-Based Authentication for the Access Token of the RingCentral login APIs
Please help me with the password-based authentication to get the access token of RingCentral through APIs from which I will download the call recordings of the voice calls.
Please help me with this issue.
I have tried the following code for this purpose but was unable to the access token:
const https = require('https');
const querystring = require('querystring');

// OAuth settings
const endpoint = '/restapi/oauth/token';
const url = 'platform.ringcentral.com';

// Client ID and secret
const clientId = 'process.env.CLIENT_ID';
const clientSecret = 'process.env.CLIENT_SECRET';

// User credentials
const username = 'process.env.USERNAME';
const password = 'process.env.PASSWORD';

// Basic authorization header
const basicAuth = Buffer.from(`${clientId}:${clientSecret}`).toString('base64');

// Request headers
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': `Basic ${basicAuth}`,
};

// Request body for the resource owner password credentials grant
const body = querystring.stringify({
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: username,
  password: password,
});

const options = {
  host: url,
  path: endpoint,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
};

// Function to make the POST request
const makeRequest = () => {
  const request = https.request(options, (response) => {
    let data = '';

    response.on('data', (chunk) => {
      data += chunk;
    });

    response.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Response:', data);
    });
  });

  request.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error.message);
  });

  request.write(body);
  request.end();
};

// Call the function to make the request
makeRequest();

But it gives me the following Error:
Response: {
  "error" : "unauthorized_client",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "OAU-251",
    "message" : "Unauthorized for this grant type"
  } ],
  "error_description" : "Unauthorized for this grant type"
}


Instead of using object and stringifying
const body = querystring.stringify({
  grant_type: 'password',
  username: username,
  password: password,
});

just directly use like this. I faced the same problem but in another programming language.
body = 'grant_type=password&username=username&password=password'

This fixed that issue for me.
